# why does fineuploader's endpoint get reset to default when i initialize for the second time in an Ember app?

Tags: ember.js, fine-uploader

bit of a specific question here since i'm using fineuploader in an ember application.

the fineuploader s3 module is loaded in a certain route in my application.  i use the didInsertElement() callback on a View to initialize it.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
     window.uploader = $('#bootstrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
         signature: { endpoint : myendoint.com/blah }
     })
}
```

it works fine the first time it is initialized.  but when i navigate away from that route, then come back to it, the didInsertElement() callback is invoked, however, the endpoint gets set to the default of "server/upload".

for those unfamiliar with Ember, when a 'Route' is navigated away from, the dom element is removed.  when you navigate back to it, the dom element is recreated from a template, then the didInsertElement callback is invoked.

it seems like there's some instance of fineuploader that's sticking around and interfering with the re-initializing of fineuploader.  none of config options are getting set.  how can i fix this?

Comment: Have you checked to validate that $('#bootstrapped-fine-uploader') exists the second time?

Comment: When using the jQuery plug-in wrapper, the instance of Fine Uploader is tied exclusively to the DOM element.  In fact, it is cached in jQuery's data store associated with that element.  If the element is removed, the data store should be cleared as well.  So, there is another piece of the puzzle missing here that is likely contributing to your issue I suspect.  Do you have a live example where this can be reproduced?

Comment: @RayNicholus can you tell me your email address? login is required, i would prefer to privately email you those details.  thanks a lot for the quick and detailed response!

Comment: @kingpin2k yes, it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your code.  When you initialize Fine Uploader, you aren't specifying a value for the `request.endpoint` option.  Instead, you later set this via the `setEndpoint` API method.  When the page first loads, some logic in your app causes your `updateFineuploaderEndpoint` function to be executed, setting the endpoint for the files.  When you navigate away from the route (and the Fine Uploader instance is destroyed) and then return to it (Fine Uploader is re-instantiated), your `updateFineuploaderEndpoint` function is NOT called again.  This means that you are never specifying an endpoint for the files, and Fine Uploader uses the default value, which is "server/upload".

Comment: ah crap, you're right.  i mistakenly thought that the first failed call i saw was for the policy endpoint, not the s3 endpoint, so i didn't check the latter.  sorry to have wasted your time and thanks for debugging my code!  i'm embarrassed.